# Relations between 3 levels and a result table

Tags: sql, normalization

I have 3 `tables` that work, let's say, as levels for this purpose. Everyone of them has 2 columns, `id` and `name`. And, they combined, result on posibilities that matches the `table 4`.

How can I create the relationships between the first set (`3 tables`), and the last one with the possible results after the combination?

I did this in the past just with `2 tables`, back then I created a third one having 2 fields, 2 `FKs` against the original tables. But this time, I have a set of 3 `tables` to match with a fourth, and that's what's making me wonder.

Should I simply create a 5th table with 4 fields having 4 `FKs` or is there another way?

Comment: a 5th used as an assignment table that links the other 3 would be your best bet. Then you can use a nested query with joins to select your data

Comment: @Takarii alright! Place the answer it if you wish so it's all done.

Comment: updated with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a 5th table as an assignment table, then using a nested query with joins you can access the data in your results table

note, the 5th table would have 3 `FK` columns linked to the 3 other tables, and a 4th for a row id.